# Method 'View' of object 'Window' failed with xlPageBreakPreview

Tags: excel, excel-2011, vba

I have a macro in which `ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView` works well. However, `ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview` returns an error `Run-time error '1004': Method 'View' of object 'Window' failed`.

Does anyone know what's wrong with that?

PS: the version of `Microsoft Visual Basic` is `14.4.2` under `Excel for Mac 2011`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the VBA editor for Mac has the `xlPageBreakPreview` property it won't be able to execute because there is no page break preview mode in Excel 2011. That is why this will always return an error when executed within Excel 2011.